# Invalid arguments at: sock.connect()

Tags: influxdb, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, influxdb-2

I want to save wind measurements I record with a Raspberry Pi Pico W to InfluxDB Cloud 2.0.

```
def send_data_to_influxdb(data):
    # Build the HTTP request
    request = (
        "POST /api/v2/write?org=haschke-florian@web.de&bucket=myBucket HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: cloud2.influxdata.com\r\n"
        "Authorization: Token myToken\r\n"
        "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        "Content-Length: {}\r\n\r\n"
        "{}"
    ).format(len(data), data)

    sock = usocket.socket()
    sock.connect(("europe-west1-1.gcp.cloud2.influxdata.com", 443))
    sock.send(request.encode("utf-8"))
    response = sock.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    sock.close()


# Sample data to send
data = [
    {
        "measurement": "test_measurement",
        "fields": {
            "value": 100
        }
    }
]

# Write data to InfluxDB
send_data_to_influxdb(ujson.dumps(data))
```

I get:

```
ValueError: invalid arguments
at: sock.connect(("europe-west1-1.gcp.cloud2.influxdata.com", 443))
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Might be worth pinging the europe-west host from your regular computer to get its IP address, then use that instead in an effort to rule out DNS issues.

Comment: The [doc](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/socket.html?highlight=sockaddr)
suggests it is more portable to use `sockaddr =
socket.getaddrinfo('www.micropython.org', 80)[0][-1]; sock.connect(sockaddr)`